# IOS Remote Notification: Must Server Keys be updated when Provisioning Profile is Changed?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I had remote notifications working beautifully!  Then they stopped working.  Is it possible that when I update the provisioning profile the server keys for push notification have to be updated as well?  That is the only thing I can recall doing since the notifications were working a few days ago that would affect them.  BTW, I added UDIDs to the Provisioning Profile -- not features.

Comment: If you just added the UDIDs then they don't need to be updated. If you're working in dev environment, you can try updating the keys as its always the best way to save time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adil Soomro Jul 12 at 19:38 said (as perfect answer):

If you just added the UDIDs then they don't need to be updated. If you're working in dev environment, you can try updating the keys as its always the best way to save time. –